# Can a synchronous HTTP request be handled asynchronously on the server?

Tags: http, asynchronous, webserver, synchronous, application-server

I'm trying to understand the terminology I see in other posts regarding synchronous and asynchronous web requests, so, in the below scenario:

The client sends a request synchronously to the server (meaning the client is blocked until it receives a response), and the server formulates the response asynchronously (it starts a new thread per request and creates the response on that thread).

Would the request itself be synchronous, but the handling of the request asynchronous?

Answer (score 0):

The client can be synchronous while the server is asynchronous, but this doesn't necessarily mean that the response is made on a new thread.

[image: Figure 4-15] Figure 4-15 of this 
[document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/architect-microservice-container-applications/communication-in-microservice-architecture) is shown above. It
depicts two cases of sync-client/async-server